# angularjs: testing a directive that uses $http and $modelValue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive that checks if a URL actually exists :

usage:

```
 <input name="urlName" type="text" url-checker  />
 <span class="danger" ng-show="urlForm.urlName.$error.urlChecker">invalid url</span>
```

and the directive code :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var directiveId = 'urlChecker';
/**
* Purpose: check whether a model's value matches a valid url 
*/
angular.module('comp.directives').directive(directiveId, ['$http', directiveFunc]);

function directiveFunc($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.bind('blur', function (e, n) {
                //check url starts with http:// or https://
                if (ngModel.$modelValue.indexOf('http://') === -1 || ngModel.$modelValue.indexOf('http://') === -1) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('urlChecker', false);
                } else {
                    //check the url actually exists
                    $http.get(ngModel.$modelValue).success(function (result) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('urlChecker', true);
                    }).error(function (error) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('urlChecker', false);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
})();
```

I have no idea how to test it. Any help would be appreciated. So far, I've done this:

```
'use strict'
describe('urlChecker', function () {
var scope, compile, element;

beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope;
    })
});

it('should should set the model validity to false', function () {

    scope.model = 'http://www.yahoo.fr';

    element = angular.element('<input type="text" ng-model="model" url-checker />');
    compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    var elm = element[0];
    elm.blur();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NgModelController:$parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). You probably shouldn't bind to input 'blur' because you might end up in conflict with the input directive.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
        if (value.indexOf('http://') === -1 || value.indexOf('http://') === -1) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('urlChecker', false);
        } else {
            //check the url actually exists
            $http.get(value).success(function (result) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('urlChecker', true);
            }).error(function (error) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('urlChecker', false);
            });
        }
        return value;
    })
}
```

Read carefully. If your parser returns undefined, ngModel won't update your model. Parsers are required to be synchronous, atm, so your async handler can't halt the user's input. You'll be able to set validity in your callback, although you have a potential race condition.

I'd probably create a controller for this directive and just push a controller method into $parsers, but you can still test this way.

```
compile(element)(scope);
scope.$digest();
var ngModel = element.controller('$ngModelController');
ngModel.$setViewValue('blah');
expect(ngModel.error['urlChecker']).toBeDefined()
```

You can also test the $http call by injecting [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend)

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('blah').respond(500)
$httpBackend.flush()
// Now your http handler should have fired.
```